# Unable to return the value after nesting while loops inside a method

Tags: java, nested, return

I'm having issue returning the DVDs object after adding the second while loop (promptAddAgain).  This function works perfect before this while loop was added.  Error during compile - cannot find symbol: variable currentDVD.

```
public DVDs getNewDVDInfo() {
    boolean keepRunning = true;
    boolean promptAddAgain = true;
    while (keepRunning) {
        String title = input.readString("Please enter the move title.");
        String releaseDate = input.readString("Please enter the release date.");
        String MPAArating = input.readString("Please enter the MPAA rating.");
        String directorName = input.readString("Please enter the director name.");
        String studio = input.readString("Please enter the name of the studio.");
        String userRating = input.readString("Please type in any comment you would "
                + "like to leave for this movie below.");

        DVDs currentDVD = new DVDs(releaseDate, MPAArating, directorName, studio, userRating);
        currentDVD.setTitle(title);

        while (promptAddAgain) {
            String userAns = input.readString("Would you like to add another DVD to the library?");
            if (userAns.equals("n")) {
                input.print("Thank you.  Returning to main menu.");
                keepRunning = false;
                promptAddAgain = false;
            } else if (userAns.equals("y")) {
                input.print("\n");
            } else {
                input.print("Unknown input, please try again.");
                keepRunning = false;
            }
        }
    }
    return currentDVD; //<--- error
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is arising because `currentDVD` is currently being defined inside the outer `while` loop, but you are referring to it outside that loop, after it has gone out of scope.  One way to fix this is to declare `currentDVD` before the first `while` loop:

```
DVDs currentDVD = null;
while (keepRunning) {
    ...
}
return currentDVD;
```

Keep in mind that with the above approach it is possible that your `getNewDVDInfo()` method might return `null`, so callers should be aware of that.

Comment: that fixed the problem.  didn't pay attention to the scoping there.  thanks!

Comment: Sure, just did.   ;)